# Berkson's error

Tags: least-squares, unbiased-estimator

1) In the case of Berkson's error the OLS is unbiaised. how to show this?
if we assume that yi= a + bxi* + ui and cov(u, x*) = 0
the true explanatory var is observed through a proxy x
xi = xi* + ni
cosidering the berkson's error we have xi*= xi + ni
assume cov (xi, ni) = 0
we have yi = a + bxi +(ni + ui)
How can we show that the OLS estimator associated with the slope of y to x is an unbiased estimator for the slope of y to x*?

2) What kind of problem is caused by the presence of Berkson's error (compared to the case you have no error at all) ? I think here that this kind of error reduces the power of a study but I am not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: What is Berkson's error?

Comment: The classical error model:  You observe the real predictor plus error
• The Berkson error model: The real predictor is what you observe plus error                                                                                                       
**The Berkson model says that
True Exposure = Observed Exposure + Error
X = W + Ub
• Note the difference:
∗ Classical: We observe true X plus error
∗ Berkson: True X is what we observe (W) plus error